# How to achieve this kind of softness in the details?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, landscape, shadows, processing

How to achieve this kind of "softness" in a details like on the image below in Photoshop? It is definitely not a blurring, there must be something else I'm missing. Tried a bunch of techniques with blur, but unsuccessfully.

[image]

Below are more examples of the details are wiped out or soften a bit (look at the mountains, grass, trees)..

p.s. Some of these photographs have an exposure time about 1/2 - 4 of a second or close to this, which is not enough to blur the details in a "natural way"..

[image]

[image]

This is a Rodney Lough Jr. Wilderness Collection and you can see more examples going to his website http://rodneyloughjr.com

Would appreciate any advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is a photo of Rodney Lough Jr. from the [Wilderness Collection](http://rodneyloughjr.com/photos/foto_folio/2), called "Day Dreaming". You have to select the image at the bottom of the page for more info and the high resolution version.

It says:

- Camera: Toyo 4x5 AII Field Camera
- Lens: 210mm
- Aperture: f64
- Exposure: 45 Seconds
- Film: Professional Fuji Velvia

The softness is coming from the long exposure time. It is not a blur, in the optical sense, it is a motion blur of the grass as the wind blows it.

The closest to reproduce the effect is to use motion blur, masked, and controlled very heavily, yet still, it would be quite a task to mimic this effect.

Comment: That's right, thanks for pointing out. I found many more examples of his photographs with the exact same effect in the details (like, trees, hills etc..) but having a much shorter exposure, say 1/2 of a second etc..

Comment: @AndriiIasynetskyi Can you show an example? The photos you show in the quesstion all have really long exposure times.